# Object list fails to append

Tags: python

I'm trying to append some objects to a list but it fails with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/miguelangel/PycharmProjects/reports/Output.py", line 23, in <module>
    product.add_item(Item('product_id', 'product_id'))
  File "/home/miguelangel/PycharmProjects/reports/Output.py", line 15, in add_item
    self.items.append(item)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I don't understand why it fails if a list is supposed to contain the append function. Here's the actual code.

```
class Item:

    def __init__(self, column: str, alias: str):
        self.column = column
        self.alias = alias


class Category:
    items = []

    def __init__(self, category: str):
        self.category = category

    def add_item(self, item: Item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def items(self):
        return self.items


product = Category('product')

product.add_item(Item('product_id', 'product_id'))
product.add_item(Item('product_name', 'product_name'))

print(product)
```

Comment: What IDE are you using, that wouldn’t alert you to the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make several mistakes here:

- you use a *class*-attribute to hold items in a category. This is a mistake because there is only *one* of those available for *all* categories. So you would add all items to essentially a global list.
- the root-cause of your problem is that you name the list items as well as the method. The latter one is shadowing the first, so when accessing `self.items` you end up with the method, that doesn't have an append method. Which is what your error tells you: a function object has no append.

Use a proper instance-variable `items` instead, and don't declare a needless accessor-method `items`. Languages like Java or C++ make you write accessors for reasons beyond the scope of this answer, but in Python one doesn't writer primitive getters and setters because attribute access is nicer, and properties are there to save the day if there would be the need for any code being run.

```
class Item:

    def __init__(self, column: str, alias: str):
        self.column = column
        self.alias = alias


class Category:

    def __init__(self, category: str):
        self.category = category
        self.items = []

    def add_item(self, item: Item):
        self.items.append(item)

product = Category('product')

product.add_item(Item('product_id', 'product_id'))
product.add_item(Item('product_name', 'product_name'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your getter for `items` clashes with the variable name. Change the variable name to `_items` or something else: it is good practice to put an underscore before private members anyways.

```
class Category:
    _items = []

    def __init__(self, category: str):
        self.category = category

    def add_item(self, item: Item):
        self._items.append(item)

    def items(self):
        return self._items
```